# What's the limit to the number of requests sent to stackAPI per second?

Tags: python, api, stackexchange-api

What's the limit to the number of requests sent to stack overflow API per second?

I set waiting time of 10 seconds, but it didn't help.

Comment: It took me 5 seconds on google to find the answer https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle

Comment: The title of this question is worded very nicely. Just need to throw it into a search engine now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Throttles](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) page details some of the rate limits, namely - no more than 30 requests per second, and a daily limit of 10,000 requests.